# Create a offline build for Testing: React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I have developed an app using React Native. But I want to give for testing to end user. So how can we create a build that loads all assets and JS files without localhost?

I searched on Google to find solutions. I got an answer that below command will help me.

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

But it won't help me anymore. Can anyone help to create a local build in iOS?

Comment: What do you mean by without localhost?

Comment: I want to give my build to end user to test design and navigation. So how can I build so that they can install application without npm start .

Comment: Do you mean like a beta testing or a local connected device?

Comment: It's beta testing.

Comment: Are you using expo or did you start your project with react-native-cli?

Comment: with react-native-cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer after doing research for last 2-3 days. Hope it will help for all React-Native developer.

Here is the answer:

--> Start your npm server to your local system using below command:

```
sudo npm run start
```

--> Above command will start your development server. Now we have to create js bundle using the following command to connect our application to js build directly:

**For iOS:**

```
$curl http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle -o main.jsbundle
```

**For Android:**

```
$curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

Above two steps will create js bundle for iOS and Android in main folder. Now follow the below step to generate an IPA and APK file.

**For iOS:**

--> Open your xcodeproj from your ios folder. Add drag main.jsbundle to your xcode project.

-->    Open AppDelegate.m file and you can bundle is loaded using one for below line of code.

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

or

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
```

**Just comment above line which is there in your code and put below line of code:**

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Now, you are good to go with iOS……

**For Android:**

Open a terminal and go to your project repo path. Compile your project using below command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

To install APK into your device:

```
adb install {PATH_TO_APK}
```

Now you are ready to go with Android too..

Hope this is will to all my kind of person….

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the need for the manually creation and addition the jsbundle please? As I know the Release configuraion for iOS takes care of it for you.

Comment: We need to load js bundle for our application. For the first time, code is having localhost, so it load from our local server, its start as soon as we run app. Release configuration of iOS is helps us to install app in particular device. But for react native, we need to start server. You can checkout this link for more info: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/running-on-device-ios.html

Comment: Release configuration of the react-native project you created takes care of the bundling js code and removes the need for the local development server. so you don't have to start the development server. It just runs for the build process and after the build completes you don't need the server any more.  The docs you gave the link for is for a really old version. I'm just trying to understand why are you doing this as an educational purpose.

Comment: for me this link worked:

`http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios`

Comment: Curl should not be used if packaging the live app. react-native bundle will produce a better optimized JS for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your react-native app through the [react-native-cli](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#creating-a-new-application) there are 2 folders in your project folder called `ios` and `androoid`. These folders contains the platform specific projects for your app.

For iOS you can open up your project with XCode and then change your build to `Release` version and build it. Later this step the beta release process is pretty much same as any other native written apps.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support. I am getting my answer. Thanks